# Apple Hardware Test result: 4HDD/11/40000000: SATA(0,0). But repaired Disk and Permissions w/o a problem

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, error, sata

Ran an Apple Hardware Test. Result: 4HDD/11/40000000: SATA(0,0). 
Then repaired Disk and Permissions. Result: Volume appears to be okay. 
But during use, sometimes it freezes randomly and my MBP restarts with the message "Your computer restarted because of a problem." Then "You shut down your computer because of a problem." 
I also got the no entry sign a few times in the past 2-3 days. But like I said, the disk repairs have no problem.
So is the disk corrupt or not or is it the cable?

Log:

```
    11/17/15 1:01:32.394 PM cloudphotosd[443]: MSSubscriber - 1456532453 Finished retrieving assets. Checking for errors on 0 assets...
11/17/15 1:07:03.795 PM cloudphotosd[443]: MSSubscriber - 1456532453 Finished retrieving assets. Checking for errors on 0 assets...
11/17/15 1:07:11.493 PM GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[701]: 2015-11-17 13:07:11.387 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[701/0xa05481d4] [lvl=2] -[KSAgentApp setupLoggerOutput] Agent settings: <KSAgentSettings:0x265830 bundleID=com.google.Keystone.Agent lastCheck=2015-11-17 08:31:29 +0000 checkInterval=18000.000000 uiDisplayInterval=604800.000000 sleepInterval=1800.000000 jitterInterval=900 maxRunInterval=0.000000 isConsoleUser=1 ticketStorePath=/Users/Safrin/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/TicketStore/Keystone.ticketstore runMode=3 daemonUpdateEngineBrokerServiceName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon.UpdateEngine daemonAdministrationServiceName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon.Administration logEverything=0 logBufferSize=2048 alwaysPromptForUpdates=0 productIDToUpdate=(null) lastUIDisplayed=(null) alwaysShowStatusItem=0 updateCheckTag=(null) printResults=NO userInitiated=NO>
11/17/15 1:07:54.606 PM WindowServer[156]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Spotlight" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
11/17/15 1:07:54.975 PM WindowServer[156]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Spotlight" after 1.37 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
11/17/15 1:08:24.807 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[703]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
11/17/15 1:08:29.244 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook.32bit[704]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook.32bit
11/17/15 1:11:50.000 PM kernel[0]: bird[262] Unable to quarantine: 93
11/17/15 1:12:02.000 PM kernel[0]: bird[262] Unable to quarantine: 93
11/17/15 1:30:21.997 PM com.apple.iCloudHelper[713]: objc[713]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
11/17/15 1:30:22.137 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
11/17/15 1:55:48.938 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coreservices.uiagent[301]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
11/17/15 1:55:48.938 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.storeuid[364]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
11/17/15 1:55:49.583 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.cloudphotosd[443]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
11/17/15 1:55:50.093 PM sessionlogoutd[734]: sessionlogoutd Launched
11/17/15 1:55:50.261 PM sessionlogoutd[734]: DEAD_PROCESS: 89 console
11/17/15 1:55:51.130 PM shutdown[736]: halt by Safrin:
11/17/15 1:55:51.130 PM shutdown[736]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1447757751 129887
11/17/15 9:28:26.000 PM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1447784906 0
11/17/15 9:28:59.000 PM syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
11/17/15 9:28:59.000 PM syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
11/17/15 9:28:59.000 PM kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
11/17/15 9:28:59.000 PM kernel[0]: PMAP: PCID enabled
11/17/15 9:28:59.000 PM kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
11/17/15 9:34:43.186 PM QuickLookSatellite[450]: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
11/17/15 9:34:43.186 PM QuickLookSatellite[450]: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
11/17/15 9:34:48.121 PM QuickLookSatellite[450]: In -[NSApplication(NSQuietSafeQuit) _updateCanQuitQuietlyAndSafely], _LSSetApplicationInformationItem(NSCanQuitQuietlyAndSafely) returned error -50
11/17/15 11:33:49.000 PM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1447792429 0
11/17/15 11:36:34.000 PM syslogd[44]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
11/17/15 11:36:34.000 PM syslogd[44]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
11/17/15 11:36:34.000 PM syslogd[44]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
```

As I just updated this^ and checked the website, the computer froze with the spinning wheel and restarted.

```
11/18/15 1:11:21.017 AM firefox[567]: Set intl.ime.nstextinput.enable to true in about:config to fix input.
11/18/15 1:11:28.479 AM mds[59]: (DiskStore.Normal:2382) b001 1.000085
11/18/15 1:13:14.685 AM firefox[567]: Set intl.ime.nstextinput.enable to true in about:config to fix input.
11/18/15 1:17:05.000 AM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1447798625 0
11/18/15 1:18:06.000 AM syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
11/18/15 1:18:06.000 AM kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
11/18/15 1:18:06.000 AM kernel[0]: PMAP: PCID enabled
11/18/15 1:18:06.000 AM kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Comment: The AHT is not 100% reliable. I had a similar issue with the Fusion Drive on my iMac - corresponding to the freezes were log entries for I/O-errors. AHT reported no problems. Look into the Console `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app` and try to narrow the timeframe to the last freeze and post the entries found there.

Comment: Also: what does "no entry sign" mean? Where did that message appear?

Comment: @J.C. http://imgur.com/9BcHk0W This was the no-entry sign that popped up several times when I restarted my mbp. I had to shut down and boot until it works or boot in Recovery mode to repair disk and then it would log in.